# how to insert data in xml file using jframe textfields

Tags: java, xml, jframe

I have text fields in Jframe, the user enters his details, then when he clicks the submit button, the details should be stored in an xml file, so how can I do that? I am completely blank in xml so do not know what to do? can you give me some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

You can set user entered data into an object. Then simply convert the object into XML file by calling XStream,
Look here the example,

```
Object dummyObject = new Object("ObjectName");
dummyObject.setValueOne(testFieldOne.getText());  //setter of dummyObject
dummyObject.setValueTwo(testFieldTwo.getText());  //setter of dummyObject
```

then simply call,

```
String xml = xstream.toXML(dummyObject);
```

Result would be like this.

```
<Object>
  <name>ObjectName</name>
  <valueOne> testFieldOne.getText() </valueOne>  
  <valueTwo> testFieldTwo.getText() </valueTwo>
</Object>
```

Hope you understand it.

Comment: I didn't get this can you please explain more for me. Thanks a lot